# Compiling LESS using Grunt above web root to custom directory

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to keep my bower/grunt stuff above web root so I can keep it under version control but also keep it secure and not publicly accessible by being above web root. I would like to compile my CSS, JS, etc to a publicly accessible web folder within web root.

I know I can go into Gruntfile.js and update all of the output paths, but is that the best way or is there a config value somewhere I could change to tell it where specifically to put the dist folder in relation to the Gruntfile?